# Implementing wait-free consensus with queues

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, concurrency, synchronization

Using Herlihy's model and definition of the wait-free hierarchy, a queue (a shared object with enqueue and dequeue) has consensus number 2, because we can initialize the queue with some value, and the first process to dequeue it "wins".

However, it is also possible to do wait-free consensus with queues that start off empty (for example, given as an assignment [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-852j-distributed-algorithms-fall-2009/assignments/MIT6_852JF09_pset6b.pdf), question 1).

I wasn't able to come up with the algorithm - would like help.

A hand-wave explanation: Two processors run asynchronously and communicate via shared memory, with atomic reads and writes being basic operations. We want to solve the wait free consensus problem, where each process starts with a bit value and they need to agree on one of the values, in a way that is wait free: each processor can finish in a finite number of its own steps, regardless of the progress of the others. A result says that such a task can't be done, so we include objects with more powerful operations that will allow consensus. The consensus number of an object is the number of processors in the model that can reach consensus using it. The consensus number of a queue with just enq and deq is 2. Intuitively it isn't 3 because if a processor deqs empty, it can't know which of the other processors deqd the value.

Comment: it would be helpful to give a ref. [Wait-free synchronization](http://cs.brown.edu/~mph/Herlihy91/p124-herlihy.pdf) / Herlily. also its hard to understand the question exactly. an algorithm that starts off with empty queues & then pushes empty values at the front is also starting off with an empty queue, isnt it? so maybe that needs to be rephrased more exactly?

Comment: You're right that understanding the subject of the paper is necessary to solve this, but the question as phrased is well defined. I don't understand what you mean by pushing empty values, but the primary issue is that if the algorithm starts by writing a value into a queue, then upon dequeueing a processor can't know whether the other processor had already dequeued. So we have to do something more subtle and utilize more than one empty queue. If you propose a specific algorithm I could tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: sorry typo that should be written "pushing initial values to the (front of the) empty queue". apparently there is a central queue that is shared by each process but no process has its own queue? a bit more of a sketch of that would be helpful. also defn of basic terms eg "wait free consensus" etc. the consensus # is apparently a concept of Herlilys framework/ hierarchy.

Comment: is the prof hinting at sec 3.4 the augmented queue with peek operation (queue initialized to empty), or is that ruled out?

Comment: Updated the question with more explanation. We are not allowed to use queue with peek, although we can (and in fact need to I believe) have more than one empty queue. Processors can operate on every queue in memory, we don't have to restrict processors to their own queue.

Answer (score 6):

This paper [Some results on the impossibility, universality, and decidability of consensus](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-56188-9_5) (by Prasad Jayanti and Sam Toueg, 1992) directly answers your question.

> We study how initialization of shared objects affects their ability to solve consensus. In particular, although a queue or a stack can solve name-consensus
> between two processes, we prove that an initially empty queue or stack **cannot**.
> However, **with a tiny extra resource such as a 1-bit safe register**, an empty queue or stack suffices to solve consensus.

Please check Section 5 for impossibility proof and algorithm.

---

Please also check the paper ["On the Importance of Registers for Computability"](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.0168.pdf) by Rati Gelashvili, Mohsen Ghaffari, Jerry Li, and Nir Shavit, 2014.

In the second paragraph of Introduction, the authors claim that:

> (1) We show that $\ldots$ ***two queues in arbitrary initial states*** are sufficient for solving two process consensus.
>
> (2) On the other hand, we prove that it is **impossible** to solve two process consensus ***using a single empty queue***.

A little conclusion is:

> In other words, unless you have multiple queues or multiple registers, a queue’s ability to solve consensus is completely dependent on its initialization.

There are many propositions/lemmas/theorems in this paper. And they are not limited to the queue object. I think it may contain what you want to know (I will read it carefully when I have time).

Comment: Don't have access to the first paper

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat Write me an email (please find my email address in my profile) and I will send you a copy.

Answer (score 2):

did not find this in a published paper/ ref so far, however here is a [similar exercise 2b](http://www.inet.tu-berlin.de/fileadmin/fg234_teaching/WS1314/NAlgorithms_WS1314/NA-Ex4.pdf) with the basic structure of the algorithm outlined (with only one small missing piece.)

> Assume now that you do not have this initialized queue, but rather you have two initially empty queues.
>   Take a look at the (incomplete) algorithm *propose<sub>i</sub>(v)*. Each process initially has a private input value
>   *v.* In the algorithm, each process first enques a winner and then a loser ball in “its queue”. Complete
>   the algorithm with the notation of the function *func<sub>i</sub>(Q<sub>j</sub> , R<sub>j</sub> , v)* so that *propose<sub>i</sub>(v)* reaches consensus
>   even if up to 1 process may fail. Make sure that you go through all the different executions and check
>   whether they give a correct result.

Algorithm 1: *propose<sub>i</sub>(v)*

> Input: v ∈ V, i ∈ {1, 2}; processes p<sub>i</sub>
>   ; empty queues Q<sub>i</sub>
>   ; register array of size 2 R<sub>i</sub>
>   [1, 2]; initially false
>   flags *flag<sub>i</sub>*
>   1. Q<sub>i</sub>.enq(”winner”);
>   2. Q<sub>i</sub>.enq(”loser”);
>   3. *flag<sub>i</sub>.*write(true);
>   4. result<sub>i</sub> = v;
>   5. for j = 1, 2 do
>   6.   if *flag<sub>j</sub>* == true then
>   7.     result<sub>i</sub> ← *func<sub>i</sub>*(Q<sub>j</sub> , R<sub>j</sub> , result<sub>i</sub>);
>   8. return result<sub>i</sub>

Comment: Thanks, my googling has failed me this time as I wasn't able to find this. I'm trying to think how to complete this.

Comment: I believe there may actually be an error and line 4 needs to read "$R_i$.write(v)". In this case I believe we can define funci(Qj , Rj , resulti) to be: deq Qj, if it's winner return "v" otherwise return $R_{1-i}$.read(). What do you think?

Comment: suggest (as written) making a table of all possibilities in the queues & algorithm flows/ time sequences. & note there may be more than one solution to this problem... possibly either inside or outside the template... & btw think this has probably been published _somewhere_...

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat Maybe check the second paragraph of Introduction of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.0168.pdf).

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat This [paper](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-56188-9_5) has also studied the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is a generic construction that turns a consensus algorithm for n processors that uses initialized objects into a consensus algorithm (for n processors) that uses n uninitialized copies of the same objects. By applying this construction to the 2-processors consensus algorithm that uses an initialized queue, one obtains a 2-processors consensus algorithm that uses 2 empty queues. The algorithm obtained has the same structure as the partial solution in [vzn's answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/43720/79284).

The generic construction is described in Section 3.1 of Elizabeth Borowsky, Eli Gafni, and Yehuda Afek. "Consensus power makes (some) sense!." Proceedings of the thirteenth annual ACM symposium on Principles of distributed computing. ACM, 1994.